# Why is Visual Studio resource editor replacing some of my constants with values on save

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022, resource-editor

I'm working on a project which has seen a lot of different Visual Studio versions over the years.

For some installations, currently with VS2022, V 17.1.3 (but also before with VS2019) whenever i edit resources and save them, some of the constants of dialog resources are replaced with numbers in the `.rc file`:

F.e. `ES_AUTOHSCROLL` is replaced by `0x80`

```
CONTROL         "",IDC_TXT,"RichEdit20W",ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP,96,115,38,12
CONTROL         "",IDC_TXT,"RichEdit20W",WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP | 0x80,96,115,38,12
```

and `ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_WANTRETURN` is replaced by `0x10c4`

```
CONTROL         "",IDC_COMMENT,"RichEdit20W",ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_WANTRETURN | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP,95,204,219,30
CONTROL         "",IDC_COMMENT,"RichEdit20W",WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP | 0x10c4,95,204,219,30
```

A seemingly arbitrary define from `Resource.h` is replaced in `DLGINIT` from

```
IDC_SOME, 0x403, 9, 0
```

to

```
1838, 0x403, 9, 0
```

even though it is defined in `Resource.h` as

```
#define IDC_SOME 1838
```

and no others are replaced.

Also a line is inserted between all bitmap and cursor resources so that

```
IDR_MAINFRAME           BITMAP                  "res\\Toolbar.bmp"
IDB_TREEITEM            BITMAP                  "res\\treeitem.bmp"
```

and

```
IDC_TRACKBALL           CURSOR                  "res\\track.cur"
IDC_ZOOMWINDOW          CURSOR                  "res\\zoom1.cur"
```

become

```
IDR_MAINFRAME           BITMAP                  "res\\Toolbar.bmp"

IDB_TREEITEM            BITMAP                  "res\\treeitem.bmp"
```

and

```
IDC_TRACKBALL           CURSOR                  "res\\track.cur"

IDC_ZOOMWINDOW          CURSOR                  "res\\zoom1.cur"
```

Is this a bug or is there a setting or property which can be used to stop this?

Comment: I also encountered the same issue. Seems like a new bug.